# How to connect to Sybase Server/Database without port number using DSN or RapidSQL? Or how to find port number?

Tags: sap-ase, dsn, isql, rapidsql

I have Some Sybase Server/Databases. I know 1. Server Name 2. Database Name 3. Username 4. Password. Using this I can connect using ISQL but while using RapidSQL it asks for port. I have existing application which uses DSN, while creating DSN also it asks for port. I am looking for 2 possiblies using RapidSQL/Creating DSN without port or How to find port mumber?

I do not have SQL.ini file.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to start-> RUN -> type `dsedit`. There will be a mneu "Select
   Directory Services"
2. Click ok on `InterfacesDriver`.
3. Highlight your server name on the left pane.

You will see its `IP/Hostname` and `Port` number on the right pane.

Answer (score 4):

If isql works then the Sybase client must have the port number defined.

On Windows, I'd expect %SYBASE%\ini\sql.ini to contain a record for your server, and you'll see the port number.

(On Unix, $SYBASE/interfaces is the equivalent file.)

I don't know if it's possible but can RapidSql use a native Sybase connection?  It sounds as if you're setting it up for ODBC?

Comment: I do not have sql.ini file, added screen shot to the question please have a look.

Comment: What is your environment variable %SYBASE% set to?  If you can connect with Sybase isql from this Windows machine then it must be set.  The fact your screen dump shows a sybase ini directory without sql.ini suggests to me that you haven't run isql from this machine, but I can't be sure.  Another thing you can do is ask the Database Administrater for the port number.